# Segmentation fault using arrays

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, segmentation-fault

Well, I've been at this forever and I know exactly where the fault is, but no clue how to fix it. I already know fgets and scanf would be better for this program, but I can't do that.

The program worked about 10 minutes ago, then I changed it and got a seg fault. Then I changed it back and still got a seg fault. Anyway, I'm sure the fresh eyes will see it right away. Have at it :D

PS: Please note my (lessthan) instead of < because I don't know how to properly leave those in my code examples still :(

```
#define WORDLENGTH 15
#define MAXLINE 1000

int main()
{
    char *line[MAXLINE];
    int i = 0;
    int j;
    int n;
    char c;


    for (n=0; c!=EOF; n++){
        char *tmp = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char)*WORDLENGTH);
        while ((c=getchar())!=' ')
            tmp[i++]=c;
        line[n]=tmp;
        i=0;
        printf("\n%s\n",line[n]); //
    }

    for(j = 0; j < n; j++){ 
        printf("\n%s\n", line[j]);  
        free (line[j]);            
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't see you ever initialized your char *line[MAXLINE];

Comment: Highlight your code and hit CTRL+K or highlight it and hit the `101` icon

Comment: Oh. How would I go about doing that if I were a good programmer?

Comment: @SiegeX - Can I just put two (whatever the name of that other thing on the tilde key is called)s around it? `<` Apparently so!

Comment: As an aside, you calling `printf("\n%s\n", line[n])`. Note that line[n] is a char without the null terminator, `\0`. This will print a stream of garbage values.

Comment: @user527179: the back ticks are for in-lining code, I don't believe it does syntax highlighting but I may be wrong. For block code you want to use CTRL+K or the 101 icon.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you are doing `line[n++] = tmp`. And then accessing `line[n]` after that. But `line[n]` hasn't been assigned.

To change it, you can print `line[n-1]` instead, but clearer would be:

```
line[n] = tmp;
i = 0;
printf(... line[n]);
```

and place the increment in the for statement instead i.e. `for (n = 0; c != EOF; n++)`.

**EDIT**

This is a summary of what I would do:

Place the `i=0` assignment at the start of the loop. Logically, it is an initialization of `i` and currently it is done in two places (at `int i = 0;` and after the assignment of `line[n]`). Both places are not near where one would expect an initialization of a variable used in the `while` loop to be.

Guard against nonsense input by checking that `i` does not exceed `WORDLENGTH-1`. Actually, I would probably code the inner `while` loop as a `for` loop on i like so:

```
for (i = 0; i < WORDLENGTH; i++) {
    tmp[i] = getchar();
    if (tmp[i] == ' ') break;
}
tmp[i] = 0;
```

or (in my character) `for(i = 0; i < WORDLENGTH; ++i) if ((tmp[i] = getchar()) == ' ') break;` followed by..

`tmp[i] = 0` to NUL-terminate the string. Since `malloc` doesn't necessarily return a 0-filled memory block.

Comment: We have a winner! Thanks a ton.

Comment: :). But seriously, updating a loop variable inside the loop tends to produce bugs when the loop is later updated.

Answer (score 1):

**there are still bugs in the suggested solution !**

1. malloc() can fail and return a NULL pointer
2. at the end of the for () the maximum i value is WORDLENGTH

so this assignment isn't correct ( out of bounds )

```
    tmp[i]= 0;
```

Can fix both with

```
char *tmp = (char *) malloc( sizeof(char) * (WORDLENGTH + 1) );
if ( tmp == NULL )      // end of available memory
    break;
```

moreover, it isn't clear if you allow EOF inside the last string.